# Joining tables in SQLite - what and how?

Tags: sqlite

I need to manipulate some data in SQLite, it should be simple but trying to figure it out how to do exactly this has frustrated me.

It's just a join, one table called "routes" has a column "stop_id". I need to take another table called "stops" which also has a "stop_id" column and everywhere that they match, add all the additional columns from "stops" to the "routes" table (added columns are "stop_name" "stop_lat" "stop_lon" and "master_station"). "stop_id" is the primary key in the stops table. I need to join the tables and not keep them relational because after I do that I will be changing the rows by hand with new information. I am using Firefox SQLite Manager if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

A join can be done with [JOIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

```
SELECT * FROM routes JOIN stops USING (stop_id)
```

However, the result of a join cannot be changed directly; the [UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement works only on actual tables.
To change values that come from the `routes` or `stops` tables, you have to update those tables by using their respective primary keys to look up the records.